# DataGridView with a checkbox with default value checked

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, checkbox

I have a dataGridView in a Winform, I added to the datagrid a column with a checkbox using  a code I saw here :

```
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    {
        column.HeaderText = "Export";
        column.Name = "Export";
        column.AutoSizeMode =
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
        column.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
        column.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell(false);
        column.CellTemplate.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
    }

    gStudyTable.Columns.Insert(0, column);
```

this works but I want the checkBox to be checked as a default saw I added :

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gStudyTable.Rows)
    {                
        row.Cells[0].Value = true;
    }
```

but the checkbox col is still unchecked. I'm using a collection as my data source and I change the value of the col after I added the data source.

Comment: You could try changing the the data source's collection instead of the cell value itself. Something like `dataSourceCollection[0].Export = true` etc...

Comment: the checkbox isn't part of my data source

Comment: you can set checkbox value to true whenever your datagrid  DataBindingComplete event raised : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/2c7fe077-095e-472f-9833-c0633eb7035f

Comment: Related [Check/Uncheck a checkbox on datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13338837/1577396)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think there is no way of setting the checked value on column declaration.
You will have to iterate through the rows checking it after datasource is set (for example in DataBindingComplete event):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1; i++)
{
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = true;
}
```

With your **column name:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1; i++)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Export"].Value = true;
}
```

Comment: It applies to all rows except the last one. Please Change the for loop to: for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++), without -1

Answer (score 3):

Try to do it like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)     
{
    row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn.Name].Value = true;     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your DataGridView is shown when you set the value of your DataGridViewCheckBoxCells: I had mine in the second tab of a TabControl and the cells were always unchecked after initialization. To solve this, I had to move cell initialization to TabControl's SelectedIndexChanged event.

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.myGridView.Rows)
        {
            ((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0]).Value = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use datatable and create columns in datagridview and then add rows, provided first column value as 'True' or 'False' for each row.

try this

Answer (score 0):

if ((bool)this.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue == true)

Comment: You probably want to put short answers like this as comments in the future.

Answer (score 0):

During or after load the value in a grid, for check the value in grid use this code and set the properties of grid column

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[0].Value = 1;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the properties within your .xsd file for the table format:

[image: Table row properties]

Then make sure you set the default value to something sensible:

[image: set default data column property value]

It will then automatically set the default value to the binding source.

Answer (score -2):

An easy way is to use the property `NewRowIndex` as shown below:

```
dvgInvoiceItems.Rows[dvgInvoiceItems.NewRowIndex-1].Cells[5].Value = true;
dvgInvoiceItems.Rows[dvgInvoiceItems.NewRowIndex-1].Cells[6].Value = true;
```