# How to Count Checked CheckBoxes count in DataGridView in WindowsForms Application

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I Have a DataGridView.In that CheckBox Column is There.if i want to Check the check box in DataGrid View One Button is Visible if no checkBox is Selected Button will be Enabled and if i Selected more then 5 checkboxes one Caution will be appered i tryed like this

```
 private void GridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {           
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell ch1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
        ch1 = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0];
        if (ch1.Value == null)
        {
            btnShow.Visible = false;
        }
        else
            btnShow.Visible = true;
   }
```

Here i did not get Exact Out Put.How can i Solve this Pls Help...

Comment: Try to see what `value` You get on check and uncheck that checkbox. I'm not sure, but I think there is something about `null`. Do You really get null value is checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: `if ch1.Value = true`

Comment: @nelek:if i check first time Button will not be appered .after so many tries if check box whether cheked or not button will be Displayed

Comment: @Fabio: if if use ch1.Value =true it shows like Cannot implicitly  convert type Object to Bool .

Comment: check this: [Get value from DataGridViewCheckBoxCell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13339133/1565525)

Comment: @fabio:I want to Count in DataGridView Events

Answer (score -1):

1. Use `CellContentClick` instead of `CellClick`. The `CheckBox` value is only triggered to change in the former.
2. Use the `CurrentCell` instead of current row `Cells[0]`, otherwise you're unnecessarily triggering this code even if you clicked in a different cell than the `CheckBoxCell` in the same row.
3. If a `CheckBoxCell` was clicked (checked/unchecked), iterate through the rows to count the number of checked cells in the correct column. The `Cell.Value` can be `null`, `true`, or `false` and the currently clicked cell will not yet reflect the new value. So instead, use `Cell.EditedFormattedValue`, which will have the updated values and will always be `true` or `false`.

For example:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if ((dataGridView1.CurrentCell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) != null)
    {
        int count = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            bool isChecked = (bool)row.Cells[0].EditedFormattedValue;

            if (isChecked)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        btnShow.Visible = count > 0; // Whatever your condition may be.

        if (count > 5)
        {
            // Your caution here. For example:
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Danger, Will Robinson!", "Caution");
        }
    }
}
```