# How to uncheck checkbox in datagridview using Entity framework

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have datagridview on winform. It is bound to result from below code:

```
PoolEntities db = new PoolEntities();

var Result = db.General_Pool_Detail.Where(g => g.Pool_Name == cbxGLType.SelectedValue && g.Mapped_Date == dt).Select(s=>                  
new { Selected = true, s.Gen_Pool_ID, s.GSL_Code, s.Amount }).ToList();

dgvGeneralPoolData.DataSource = Result;
```

The code works perfectly fine. But when I uncheck the checkbox on datagridview it does not work.

In datagirdview event i have written the following code:

```
private void dgvGeneralPoolData_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvGeneralPoolData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Selected)
        {
Boolean IsChecked = (Boolean) dgvGeneralPoolData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;

            if (IsChecked)
            {
              dgvGeneralPoolData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I want to save the changes made in datagridview to the database.
Please help.

Comment: it seems that this was asked before, check out this post: [Check/Uncheck a checkbox on datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338837/check-uncheck-a-checkbox-on-datagridview)

Comment: @SteliosH ... I have checked the code but it still does not work. Please note the SELECTED column is not from database table, it is created in LINQ code.

Answer (score 0):

***EditMode Property***

1. check editmode property of your datagridview.

Comment: By setting   dgvGeneralPoolData.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter; but still it does not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: I have resolved the problem by using BindingNavigator and BindingSource controls. Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Does it even hit your click event? Where exactly does it break when you debug? Try to debug and provide some more info if you can.

1) Debug and make sure that the event handler does work. Sometimes when you copy paste the code the event handler doesn't get register by the designer so try deleting the CellClick and type the code again on the grid view, when you add the = sign it should give you an option to create the ClickCell method for you. It should be something like this inside your click event.

```
if (e.RowIndex != -1)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvGeneralPoolData.CurrentRow.Cells["ColumnNumberHere"];
    if (chk.Value == null || chk.Value = false)
    { 
        chk.Value = true;
    }
    else
    {
        chk.Value = false
    }
}
```

2) Make sure this is under your InitializeComponent()

```
this.dgvGeneralPoolData.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dgvGeneralPoolData_CellContentClick);
```

Comment: CellClick event handler is registered and fired when click but CheckBox is not unchecked when click. Is this the problem with field SELECTED in LINQ code or anything else.