# C# Winform datagrid checkbox checked

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am adding a checkbox to my datagrid (index 5) - but how do i set the checkbox so "checked" by default?

I can't figure out how to do it - i've tried different versions, but nothing helps - everytime i run the code it just comes up with the checkbox unchecked.

// Edit - updated the entire code

```
        public void popuplateDataGrid()
    {

        selectQueryString = "SELECT LinesEntry.item, LinesEntry.Description, LinesEntry.deliver * -1 as 'Bestilt', i.QuantityPrColi as 'Kolli antal'  FROM LinesEntry inner join Orders on Orders.OrderNo = linesEntry.OrderNo inner join inventory i on i.item = linesEntry.item where Orders.Orderno='23838' ";

        sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQueryString, KompasInterface.SqlConnectionStringCompany);
        sqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter);

        dataTable = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;

        // Add them to the list 
        dataGridItems.DataSource = bindingSource;

        //Item Data Source
        string selectQueryStringItem = "SELECT Supplier, Supplier + ' - ' + Name as Name From Suppliers";

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapterItem = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQueryStringItem, KompasInterface.SqlConnectionStringCompany);
        SqlCommandBuilder sqlCommandBuilderItem = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapterItem);

        DataTable dtSupplier = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdapterItem.Fill(dtSupplier);
        BindingSource bindSourceSupplier = new BindingSource();
        bindSourceSupplier.DataSource = dtSupplier;

        //Adding  Month Combo
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ColumnMonth = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        ColumnMonth.DataPropertyName = "Supplier";
        ColumnMonth.HeaderText = "Leverandør nr.";
        ColumnMonth.Width = 200;

        ColumnMonth.DataSource = bindSourceSupplier;
        ColumnMonth.ValueMember = "Supplier";
        ColumnMonth.DisplayMember = "Name";

        ColumnMonth.AutoComplete = true;


        dataGridItems.Columns.Add(ColumnMonth);

        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn(false);
        dataGridItems.Columns.Add(chk);
        chk.HeaderText = "Medtag";
        chk.Name = "Include";
        chk.FalseValue = false;
        chk.TrueValue = true;
        chk.Selected = true;
        //chk.Value = true;


        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridItems.Rows)
        {

            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkBox = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[5];
            chkBox.Value = true;
            if (chkBox.Value == chkBox.TrueValue)
            {
                chkBox.Value = chkBox.FalseValue;
            }
            else
            {
                chkBox.Value = chkBox.TrueValue;
            }

            chkBox.Value = true;


        }


    }
```

Comment: Did you try to set the ckBox.Value to `true`?

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov You've linked column instead of cell...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check/Uncheck a checkbox on datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338837/check-uncheck-a-checkbox-on-datagridview)

Comment: The property `Selected` refers to whether the cell is focused or not. The property `Value` however refers to the contents of the cell. A checkbox has a `boolean` value, therefore you need to set `chkBox.Value = true`

Comment: chkBox.Value = true; - is not working, i have tried that.

Answer (score 2):

I stepped over this, and it seemed to fix my issue

chk.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = true;

Answer (score -1):

The property `Selected` refers to whether the cell is focused or not.
try
`checkBox1.Value = true`
or try changing it to true in the objects properties window