# Clear TextBoxes when uncheck CheckBox in Data DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

With this a CheckBox in a DataGridView2 in FormLoad

```
  Dim chk1 As DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn = New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
  DataGridView2.Columns.Add(chk1)
  chk1.HeaderText = "Keuze"
  chk1.Name = "chk"
```

When select a CheckBox filling some textboxes

```
 Private Sub DataGridView2_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellContentClick
     If e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
         For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
             row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = False
         Next
     End If
     Dim senderGrid As DataGridView = sender
     Dim data = senderGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem

     If senderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).GetType() Is GetType(DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn) And e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
         TBterug.Text = DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells("Todo").Value.ToString()
         CBbelangrijkterug.Text = DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells("Belangrijk").Value.ToString()
         Id.Text = DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells("Id").Value.ToString()
         LBdelete.Visible = True
         LBuncheck.Visible = True
     End If

 End Sub
```

But when i Uncheck the CheckBox i want to Empty the TextBoxes , what do i have to add to make this work ?

I tryed this but no luck [Check/Uncheck a checkbox on datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338837/check-uncheck-a-checkbox-on-datagridview)

Comment: Looks like the first thing you do is clear out the check mark, is that correct?

Comment: I can only select one CheckBox then it fills the TextBoxes.  Yes , first i want to uncheck it and then it has to clear the Textboxes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer dr.null i will take a look at it.

But for now.
Found a solution here , and made it work with a ButtonClick.
Used this `chk.Value = chk.FalseValue`

[Check/Uncheck a checkbox on datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338837/check-uncheck-a-checkbox-on-datagridview)

In FormLoad

```
Dim CheckboxColumn As DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn = New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
CheckboxColumn.TrueValue = True
CheckboxColumn.FalseValue = False
CheckboxColumn.Width = 10
DataGridView2.Columns.Add(CheckboxColumn)
DataGridView2.Rows.Add(1)
CheckboxColumn.HeaderText = "Keuze"
CheckboxColumn.Name = "chk"
```

And

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellContentClick
     If e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
         For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
             row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = False
         Next
     End If
     Dim senderGrid As DataGridView = sender
     Dim data = senderGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem

     If senderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).GetType() Is GetType(DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn) And e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
         TBterug.Text = DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells("Todo").Value.ToString()
         CBbelangrijkterug.Text = DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells("Belangrijk").Value.ToString()
         Id.Text = DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells("Id").Value.ToString()
         BTdelete.Visible = True
         BTreturn.Visible = True

     End If

End Sub
```

Added a Button

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTreturn.Click
     For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
         Dim chk As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = CType(row.Cells(0), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)

         If chk.Value = chk.FalseValue OrElse chk.Value Is Nothing Then

         Else

             chk.Value = chk.FalseValue
             TBterug.Text = ""
             CBbelangrijkterug.Text = ""
             Id.Text = ""
             TBnieuw.Text = ""
             CBbelangrijk.Text = ""
             Id.Text = ""
             BTdelete.Visible = False
             BTreturn.Visible = False
         End If
     Next

     DataGridView2.EndEdit()
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow only one selection, don't wait for another selection to be committed and take early action to prevent it. In the `DataGridView` control, such action can be taken by handling the [CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) to call the [`DataGridView.CancelEdit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.canceledit?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CancelEdit)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) method if the [CurrentCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CurrentCell)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) belongs to the target `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` and it's not currently checked but it's [dirty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.iscurrentcelldirty?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) and there are uncommitted changes.

For example:

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView2_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

    If TypeOf dgv.CurrentCell Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell AndAlso
        dgv.IsCurrentCellDirty AndAlso
        Not CBool(dgv.CurrentCell.FormattedValue) Then

        Dim col = dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex

        If dgv.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).
            Any(Function(row) CBool(row.Cells(col).FormattedValue)) Then
            dgv.CancelEdit()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, to reset the display and command controls before committing the changes, handle the [DataGridView.CellContentClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick?view=netframework-4.8) event to clear and fill/show/enable the controls if the [DataGridViewCell.EditedFormattedValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.editedformattedvalue?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.EditedFormattedValue)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) property is true, or just clear/disable/hide them if the [DataGridViewCell.FormattedValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.formattedvalue?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.FormattedValue)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) property is true.

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellContentClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        If CBool(dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).EditedFormattedValue) Then
            ResetControls(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex))
        ElseIf CBool(dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).FormattedValue) Then
            ResetControls()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ResetControls(Optional row As DataGridViewRow = Nothing)
    If row IsNot Nothing Then
        TBterug.Text = row.Cells("Todo").Value?.ToString()
        CBbelangrijkterug.Text = row.Cells("Belangrijk").Value?.ToString()
        Id.Text = row.Cells("Id").Value?.ToString()
        LBdelete.Visible = True
        LBuncheck.Visible = True
    Else
        TBterug.Text = ""
        Id.Text = ""
        CBbelangrijkterug.Text = ""
        LBdelete.Visible = False
        LBuncheck.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```